# Is there a way to remove lighting and make everything have the same light?

Tags: lighting, shadows

[image]

It looks like there is no lighting and the only source is my camera? How can I make everything white in the sphere without shading/lighting?

Comment: You can use an emision shader, set the color and plug it into the material output directly

Answer (score 1):

**Your [Viewport Shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html) (<kbd>Z</kbd>) is set to `Solid` mode.** In this mode you get a quick render of the model with the *Workbench* render engine.

Check the settings in the drop-down menu. There you will see the studio light (the grey sphere) that controls the lighting. You can click the sphere to choose another light setup.

The color can be changed here, too. If the color mode is set to `Material` then it uses the colors defined in the *Material Properties* tab > *Viewport Display*. That's the *Workbench* settings, while the material colors above are used by the *Eevee* and *Cycles* render engines.

[image: solid mode]

**To see what the actual render will look like set Viewport Shading to `Rendered`**. This mode also offers options. Make sure you have ticked the *Scene Lights* and *Scene World* options.

To see the lights in the final render (<kbd>F12</kbd>) they must be enabled for render. It's the "camera" icon in the outliner.

The *Scene World* settings you can change in the *World Properties* tab or in the *Shader Editor* when you select `World` from the drop-down box.

[image: rendered mode]

(The node set up here is used to use the [HDRI](https://polyhaven.com/a/autoshop_01) for lighting only and to hide it when the *MixShader* node is enabled. Nodes can be muted (disabled) by key <kbd>M</kbd> or use the context menu.

Side note: If you want to use Cycles and have a supported graphics card, set *Device* to `GPU` for faster rendering.)